# foldl . foldr function composition - Haskell

Tags: haskell, fold, function-composition

So, I'm really frying my brain trying do understand the foldl.foldr composition.
Here is a example:

```
(foldl.foldr) (+) 1 [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

The result is 22, but what's really happening here?

To me it looks like this is what is happening: `foldl (+) 1 [6,15]`.
My doubt is related to the `foldr` part. Shouldn't it add the 1 to all the sub-lists? Like this: `foldr (+) 1 [1,2,3]`.
In my head the 1 is added just one time, is it right? (probably not, but I want to know how/why!).

I'm very confused (and perhaps making all the confusion, haha).
Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
(foldl.foldr) (+) 1 [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

becomes

```
foldl (foldr (+)) 1 [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

So you get

```
foldl (foldr (+)) (foldr (+) 1 [1,2,3]) [[4,5,6]]
```

after the first step of `foldl`, or

```
foldl (foldr (+)) 7 [[4,5,6]]
```

if we evaluate the applied `foldr` (unless the strictness analyser kicks in, it would in reality remain an unevaluated thunk until the `foldl` has traversed the entire list, but the next expression is more readable with it evaluated), and that becomes

```
foldl (foldr (+)) (foldr (+) 7 [4,5,6]) []
```

and finally

```
foldl (foldr (+)) 22 []
~> 22
```

Comment: I don't think this is the correct sequence of applications, Daniel. `7` won't be forced as early as you show, IMO.

Comment: Yes, it would - barring optimisations - remain a thunk until the final resulting thunk produced by the `foldl` is evaluated. But evaluating it prematurely was less to type and makes it more readable.

Answer (score 13):

Let's examine `foldl . foldr`. Their types are

```
foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> (a -> [b] -> a)
foldr :: (c -> d -> d) -> (d -> [c] -> d)
```

I intentionally used distinct type variables and I added parentheses so that it becomes more apparent that we view them now as functions of one argument (and their results are functions). Looking at `foldl` we see that it is a kind of lifting function: Given a function that produces `a` from `a` using `b`, we lift it so that it works on `[b]` (by repeating the computation). Function `foldr` is similar, just with arguments reversed.

Now what happens if we apply `foldl . foldr`? First, let's derive the type: We have to unify the type variables so that the result of `foldr` matches the argument of `foldl`. So we have to substitute: `a = d, b = [c]`:

```
foldl :: (d -> [c] -> d) -> (d -> [[c]] -> d)
foldr :: (c -> d   -> d) -> (d -> [c] -> d)
```

So we get

```
foldl . foldr :: (c -> d -> d) -> (d -> [[c]] -> d)
```

And what is its meaning? First, `foldr` lifts the argument of type `c -> d -> d` to work on lists, and reverses its arguments so that we get `d -> [c] -> d`. Next, `foldl` lifts this function again to work on `[[c]]` - lists of `[c]`.

In your case, the operation being lifted `(+)` is associative, so we don't have care about the order of its application. The double lifting simply creates a function that applies the operation on all the nested elements.

If we use just `foldl`, the effect is even nicer: We can lift multiple times, like in

```
foldl . foldl . foldl . foldl
    :: (a -> b -> a) -> (a -> [[[[b]]]] -> a)
```

Comment: Even for an associative operation the correct sequence of applications matters, as it can have a (potentially great) impact on performance.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `(foldl.foldr) f z xs === foldr f z (concat $ reverse xs)`.

Even if `f` is an associative operation, the correct sequence of applications matters, as it can have an impact on performance.

We begin with

```
(foldl.foldr) f z xs
foldl (foldr f) z xs
```

writing with `g = foldr f` and `[x1,x2,...,xn_1,xn] = xs` for a moment, this is

```
(...((z `g` x1) `g` x2) ... `g` xn)
(`g` xn) ((`g` xn_1) ... ((`g` x1) z) ... )
foldr f z $ concat [xn,xn_1, ..., x1]
foldr f z $ concat $ reverse xs
```

So in your case the correct reduction sequence is

```
(foldl.foldr) 1 [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
4+(5+(6+(  1+(2+(3+  1)))))
22
```

To wit,

```
Prelude> (foldl.foldr) (:) [] [[1..3],[4..6],[7..8]]
[7,8,4,5,6,1,2,3]
```

---

Similarly, `(foldl.foldl) f z xs == foldl f z $ concat xs`. With `snoc a b = a++[b]`,

```
Prelude> (foldl.foldl) snoc [] [[1..3],[4..6],[7..8]]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Also, `(foldl.foldl.foldl) f z xs == (foldl.foldl) (foldl f) z xs == foldl (foldl f) z $ concat xs == (foldl.foldl) f z $ concat xs == foldl f z $ concat (concat xs)`, etc.:

```
Prelude> (foldl.foldl.foldl) snoc [] [[[1..3],[4..6]],[[7..8]]]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
Prelude> (foldl.foldr.foldl) snoc [] [[[1..3],[4..6]],[[7..8]]]
[7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6]
Prelude> (foldl.foldl.foldr) (:) [] [[[1..3],[4..6]],[[7..8]]]
[7,8,4,5,6,1,2,3]
```